# automatic form post data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with lots of data to be posted, so i was wondering if there is any way to get all the data to be posted automatically.

like for example i sent data this way

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'http://mymegafiles.com/rapidleech/index.php',
        data: 'link=' + $('#link').val() + '&yt_fmt' + $('#yt_fmt').val(),

     });
```

but there are so many fields that it doesnt look a good idea to me.

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'post',
    url: 'http://mymegafiles.com/rapidleech/index.php',
    data: $('#formId').serialize()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the fields are all part of a form, you'll be wanting to use [$('form').serialize()](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/serialize)

Answer (score 0):

You can just call '.submit()' on the form?